# Запрос геолокации с браузера

Tags: html, webbrowser

Какими методами можно делать запросы с браузера на геолокацию ? Чтобы возвращало на подобии такого: `43.048538, 44.692945`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делаю так:

```js
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var location_timeout = setTimeout(geolocFail, 10000);
        function geo_success(position) {
            clearTimeout(location_timeout);
            yourLat = position.coords.latitude;
            yourLng = position.coords.longitude;
            //alert(yourLat + " , " + yourLng);
        };
        function geo_error(error) {
            clearTimeout(location_timeout);
            if(error.code == 1) alert("Местоположение не определенно");
            if(error.code == 2) alert("Сеть не активна");
            if(error.code == 3) alert("Превышено время ожидания");
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, geo_error, geo_options);
      } else {
        geolocFail();
      };
      function geolocFail(){
          alert("Ваш браузер не поддерживает гео-локацию");
      };
```

yourLat и yourLng  - это как раз нужные тебе координаты.
Но нужно чтобы юзер разрешил взять его координаты, без этого никак.

Comment: Спасибо огромное) Но у меня на двух браузерах выдает ошибку:  ReferenceError: geo_options is not defined

Comment: Работает только с SSL)